# How Do I Apply A Single Terraform Module?

Tags: terraform

I have a single `main.tf` at the root and different modules under it for different parts of my Azure cloud e.g.

```
main.tf
  - apim
  - firewall
  - ftp
  - function
```

The `main.tf` passes variable down to the various modules e.g. resource group name or a map of tags.

During *development* I have been investigating certain functionality using the portal and I don't have it in terraform yet.

e.g. working out how best to add a mock service in the web module

If I now want to update a different module (e.g. update firewall rules) terraform will suggest destroying the added service.

How can I do `terraform plan/apply` for just a single module?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can target only the module by specifying the module namespace as the `target` argument in your `plan` and `apply` commands:

```
terraform plan -target=module.<declared module name>
```

For example, if your module declaration was:

```
module "the_firewall" {
  source = "${path.root}/firewall"
}
```

then the command would be:

```
terraform plan -target=module.the_firewall
```

to only target that module declaration.

Note that this should only be used in development/testing scenarios, which it seems you already are focused on according to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Per Matthew's answer, I found that terraform didn't like `-target=module.<declared module name>`

My terraform plan / apply works with:

```
terraform plan -target module.<declared module name>
```

In addition, it's also sometimes helpful to use -target to destroy a module (again, only if it arises during development / testing).

For example:

```
terraform destroy -target module.the_firewall
```

This is using terraform version: 1.3.9